# Bitlocker: Manage-bde unable to unlock drive: "The current directory is invalid." error occurs

Tags: windows-7, encryption, bitlocker

I've encrypted one of my drives with Bitlocker and am successfully able to lock the drive via manage-bde with the following command

```
manage-bde -lock H: -ForceDismount
```

However, when I try to unlock the drive via manage-bde with the following command

`manage-bde -unlock H: -password`

I get the error "The current directory is invalid." instead of being prompted to enter my password.

Does anyone know how to properly unlock a drive via manage-bde?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! In my command prompt, the current working directory was the root of the drive I had just locked! So, my command prompt looked like this

`H:\>manage-bde -unlock H: -password`

Simply changing directories and running the command again solved the problem!